# Rancher v2.4.4 Istio end-user authentication error no matches for kind "RequestAuthentication"

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, istio

i'm trying to use istio end-user authentication example with latest rancher, but I'm getting below error

```
unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "RequestAuthentication" in version "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
```

when I use below command

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: "jwt-example"
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "testing@secure.istio.io"
    jwksUri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.6/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json"
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this support matrix](https://rancher.com/support-maintenance-terms/all-supported-versions/rancher-v2.4.4/) from rancher website,the istio version given is 1.4.7.

RequestAuthentication kind was introduced in istio in the version 1.5.So you might be applying the incorrect resource in this version.See [this](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/#authentication-policy) for istio's upgrade notes on 1.5.Since rancher is having not the latest version ,you will have to apply the old policy resources.You can find 1.4 docs at https://archive.istio.io/v1.4/docs/

Hope this helps.